# how I can to get the attribute of children in java at xml file?

Tags: java, xml

I am read the xml file in javascripts and java , in javascripts I read it fine but in java I found it difficult , this is the part of my xml file :

```
<Objects>
<TemplateDef title="false" >
<fields relType="0">
<TemplateField  englishName="Login" >
<fieldType relType="2">
<TemplateFieldType  visibleName="String" realType="String" />
</fieldType>
</TemplateField>
<TemplateDef title="false" >
<fields relType="0">
<TemplateField  englishName="Login1" >
<fieldType relType="2">
<TemplateFieldType  visibleName="int" realType="int" />
</fieldType>
</TemplateField>
</TemplateDef >
</Objects>
```

I want to access to the attribute of "visibleName"  I can do it in javascripts by the code :

```
var obj1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TemplateDef");
                        objattr=obj1[1].getElementsByTagName("TemplateField");
                          for (var i = 0; i< objattr.length; i++) 
                          {
                              //alert(y[5].getAttribute('name'));
                              if(objattr[i].getAttribute('name')!==null&&objattr[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('visibleName')!==null)
                                  {
                                  }
                          }
```

But I try to write to write the same code in java to access to attributes "visiablename" and I faild , my try in java :

```
            Element  nodeclass =(Element) nList.item(1);
                NodeList nList1 = nodeclass.getElementsByTagName("TemplateField");
                  for (int i = 0; i< nList1.getLength(); i++) 
                  {
                      Node tempnode = nList1.item(i);
                      if (tempnode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {

                            Element eElement = (Element) tempnode;
                            if(eElement.getAttribute("name")!=null && eElement.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getAttribute("visibleName")!=null)
// here error because getAttribute not take parameter as string
                               {

                               }
                      }
```

the compiler error here 
eElement.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getAttribute("visibleName")!=null)
**// here error because getAttribute not take parameter as string**

so can any body help me to write the code in java ?

Comment: "getFirstChild" returns a Node, you must cast it to 'Element' to access to "getAttribute" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert to Element:

```
Element e = (Element)eElement.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
String visibleName = e.getAttribute("visibleName");
```

Comment: it work thanks , I will accept your answer after 2 minutes